# How to get Google maps API - API key

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get the Google maps working on my app. I understand that I need the API key to put in my manifest file. Ok so far so good. I have done this and I have registered my app and now I am stuck on a screen just showing me the information about my app (that I have entered before) and nothing more. I don't see any keys nor nothing. Is there something else to do?

Comment: did you read this doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Read and go step by step, you will get all your answers.

Comment: I did and I am on the step "Obtain a Google Maps API key". However I dont see any "Create New Android Key..." buttons.

Comment: First you need to register yourself to Google APIs Console. And follow the steps under Obtain a Google Maps API key.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Go through the above link and read the step by step procedure.
Install the Android SDK.
Download and configure the Google Play services SDK, which includes the Google Maps Android API. If you use the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business you must download and configure the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business static library.
Obtain an API key. To do this, you will need to register a project in the Google APIs Console, and get a signing certificate for your app.
Add the required settings in your application's manifest.
Add a map to your application.
Publish your application.